# how to format the UIDatepiker Date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uidatepicker

I need to know how to get date d-m-y like this example 4-5-2011 specially without minutes, hours and the +0000

the code :

```
CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

UIDatePicker *pickerVieww = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];

    pickerVieww.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    pickerVieww.datePickerMode= UIDatePickerModeDate; 
    //datePicker.maximumDate=[NSDate date]; 

    [pickerVieww addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(pickerChanged:)  
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    pickerVieww.minimumDate =  [NSDate date];
    [pickeView release];
```

I got this date from `pickerChanged` 2012-11-14 22:00:00 +0000

any idea thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do this once that datePickingDone

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateformat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YY"];
        NSString *formattedDate=[dateformat stringFromDate:urReceivedDate];
    [dateformat release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use 
`+ (NSString *)localizedStringFromDate:(NSDate *)date dateStyle:(NSDateFormatterStyle)dateStyle timeStyle:(NSDateFormatterStyle)timeStyle`:

```
 NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date 
                                   dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle 
                                   timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

Nice thing about that is, it handles localization for you (and it's nice and short of course). Checkout the differen NSDateFormatterStyles, to find the one you need.